# Can I `use strict` to observe runtime error?

Tags: perl

Say I have massive perl scripts don't `use stirct` at all, and I only want to observe runtime errors if `use strict` on them.  Can I do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $foo = '1';
my @bar = @{$foo};  # wrong!

print "done";

1;
```

STDOUT:

```
done
```

STDERR:

```
Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 5.
```

Comment: Would `use strict 'refs'` work?

Comment: I want error messages from `use strict`, but also want scripts to be executable as if they don't have `use strict`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need